# SQL invalid identifier error

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jdbc, oracle10g

I was working on jdbc my sql statements.My table TBGROUP has these two columns GroupName,OwnerEmail and

```
String n1=request.getParameter("GName");

String n3=request.getParameter("OEmail");


String sql1 = "SELECT GroupName,OwnerEmail FROM TBGROUP where GroupName='"+n1+"' and OwnerEmail='"+n3+"'";
```

But it gives an error on Tomcat output screen that "OWNEREMAIL": invalid identifier.
What can be the reason.Please help

Comment: Depending on your db, the cols may be case sensitive.

Comment: @markg am using oracle 10g

Comment: SQL Injection, here I come! That is, please do not build query strings by string concatenation, please use [prepared statements][(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead.

Comment: try `GroupName like '"+n1+"' and OwnerEmail like '"+n3+"'"  instead of `=`.

Comment: Hmmm... are you connecting as the right user/schema? Maybe you need to include schemaname

Comment: @JeanHominal Sorry,But am using this sql1 in myResultSet statement.So,please tell whats wrong in this sql query

Comment: @Caffè Sorry,STILL SAME ERROR..:(

Comment: @markg NO,If i remove this statement the code runs fine .Make the connection ,inserts the data too.

Comment: @user3445854 . . . The error is saying that the table `TBGROUP` in the schema you are connected to does not have the column `OwnerEmail`.  There is no way that we can verify that the table really does have the column.  Case sensitivity is one possibility.  Misspelling the intended column name is another.  Connection to the wrong schema is yet another.  And there are probably half a dozen other reasons that don't come immediately to mind.

Answer (score 0):

The TBGROUP table doesn't have a column called OWNEREMAIL